# Date getting converted incorrectly from angular to web api controller

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, angular6

Hi i am calling web api action from angular passing date , converting date in angular before calling as below it returns output as Wed Mar 24 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) when i alert.

```
element.EndDate = new Date(element.EndDate);
```

but in web api controller it is getting as 23-03-2019 06:30:00 PM

don't know why this incorrect conversion is happening i am using DateTime in c# for storing the Date and in angular Date type;

Comment: I think you'd be more likely to get an answer if you were more explicit in how the various bits of your application flow together.  For example: The user enters a date using a DatePicker in my Angular App, I take the date (this value XXX) and format JSON (that looks like this) and post it to my WebApi app.  The WebApi app takes the JSON and creates a DateTime (value = YYY).  And so on.  Your question doesn't quite have enough information

Comment: `DateTime` has no offset which means `Wed Mar 24 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530` will be converted to the web server's timezone. Either send UTC times only or use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime on the server

Comment: The api is returning Wed Mar 24 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0530 (minus instead of plus).  India time should be later than UTC.  Not sure where the error is occurring.

Comment: @jdweng it *is* later. It's `Mar 24 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530`. If the server is at UTC, as most cloud servers are, the UTC time will be March 23 06:30:00 PM. Try `DateTimeOffset.Parse("2019-03-24T00:00:00+0530").ToUniversalTime()`

Comment: Let say it is Midnight March 24 UTC in London.  Then NYC is GMT-5 which will be March 23 07:00:00 PM.  So you are saying if NYC is 7PM then India is 6:30PM?

Comment: What is happening is the api is getting UTF time.  So 23-03-2019 06:30:00 PM is indicating the time in London.  India time would be March 24 2019 00:00:00.  So time should be March 23 2019 18:30:00+0530.